# SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized

Tags: python, jinja2, webapp2

so i am trying webapp2 first time with jinja2. Here is my code

```
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2

from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape






JINJA_ENVIROMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates'),
    autoescape = select_autoescape()
)

jinja_var = {
    'title': 'this is a test content page'
}

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def appear_template(self):

        template = JINJA_ENVIROMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(jinja_var))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/.*', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

and i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\unfge\Desktop\ProjectW\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import webapp2
  File "C:\Users\unfge\Desktop\ProjectW\wdi\lib\site-packages\webapp2.py", line 571
    except Exception, e:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
```

I do not know what the problem is since i am new to this. I would appreciate any help

Comment: You're trying to use an old Python 2.x module under a recent version of Python - the current syntax for that line is `except Exception as e:`.

Comment: I'm not up on all the details, but I know that things have changed in this area as Python has matured.  So maybe you have an older version of webapp2 that you would want to update?

Comment: what is the latest version of webapp2? 2.5.2 right?